# Find negative fractional power of a matrix in Armadillo

Tags: armadillo

In Matlab I do  `A ^ -0.5` to find the negative fractional power of matrix `A`. What is the equivalent in Armadillo C++ library? The `pow()` function performs element wise operation.

Comment: You could diagonalize the matrix first, then element-wise operations are fine.

Comment: So there is no Armadillo API to do this, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Armadillo, but mathematically, this needs to happen in any way  - see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732511/fractional-power-of-matrix
In order to take a fractional power of a matrix, the matrix needs to be diagonizable, otherwise this is not defined at all. If it is, then the fractional power is defined by the element-wise application of the power to the eigenvalues (i.e. diagonal elemnets)

Comment: I'm  sure Armadillo has some LU-decomposition method, this will do just nicely (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)

Comment: Use the [powmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#powmat) function.  `cx_mat B = powmat(A, -0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
expmat(-0.5 * logmat(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [powmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#powmat) function, like so:

```
mat A(5,5,fill::randu);
cx_mat B = powmat(A, -0.5);
```

Or use a combination of [inv()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#inv) and [sqrtmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat).